# What packages are needed for playing live streams of youtube?

Tags: firefox, browser, streaming, youtube, gstreamer

I have been trying to play live streams on youtube, but it does not play any at all.
Everything it says its that the browser does not support it (html5).

So what packages are missing in order to being able to play it?

Kernel> 4.18.7 (64 bits)
Opensuse thumbleweed
Firefox 68.0.1

[image]

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Ned64, I discover that this is a issue related to the distro (suse) and its discussed the only method to solve [here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Firefox_MP4/H.264_Video_Support)
[image]
ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the x264 media player in Firefox by Cisco which is usually already built-in (do not install anything).  Please check it by looking at the list of installed plugins within Firefox: `Menu: Add-Ons -> Plugins`

Reference: [Firefox's Open-H.264 plugin](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/open-h264-plugin-firefox)

You could, now, however, be hit by this new bug here:

[Bug: Firefox for Android no longer automatically downloads the Cisco OpenH264 plugin as of version 68](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-android-openh264)

Since this change was introduced by Mozilla in version 68, you could downgrading to a lower version - perhaps the latest LTS version?! - and try playing the video.  According to Mozilla (second reference above), an existing plugin will not be uninstalled which means that once you have the plugin (check the Firefox menu), you could try upgrading again.

If you have installed the mentioned plugin and still cannot play some HTML5 content, here is an entry in openSUSE Linux's support database:

[SDB: Firefox MP4/H.264 Video Support](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Firefox_MP4/H.264_Video_Support)

(in short, due to patent issues some packages are missing from openSUSE but the well-known [Packman repository for SuSE](https://en.opensuse.org/Additional_package_repositories#Packman) provides the necessary `libav*` packages. They are also automatically pulled in if you enable the Packman repo and then install `vlc` *from that repo* (select it in `yast2 sw_single`) or use `zypper`).

Comment: Thanks for the info, the 264 player was installed, and it is not the case of the new bug, but besides I have to install a whole pack of files

Comment: your answer lead me to https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Firefox_MP4/H.264_Video_Support that indeed lists the issue, and mark the method as the only solution

Comment: @riccs_0x Thanks for the info, I added that link and explanation in my answer in case someone else has that problem.